# Laravel : Best way to call a collection of elements on all my pages (menu)

Tags: laravel

I have a menu in a header.blade.php file.

I did something like this :

```
@php $elements = \App\Http\Controllers\ElementController::getElements(); @endphp
@foreach ($elements as $element)
@endforeach
```

It works but it's make me feel bad to use @php in my template.

I'm pretty sure this is a better way to load a collection of Elements for all my page. 
I was thinking about using AppServiceProvider->boot() function ? 
Would it be the cleanest way ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you attempted passing the values of this element in your controller function via `view()` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AppServiceProvider` looks better option.

```
   <?php

    namespace App\Providers;

    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

    class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
    {

     public function boot()
    {
     $elements = \App\Http\Controllers\ElementController::getElements();

     View::share('elements', $elements);
     }


    public function register()
   {
    //
   }
 }
```

Or using `BaseController`

```
  class BaseController extends Controller
 {
 public function __construct()
 {
  $elements = \App\Http\Controllers\ElementController::getElements()

   View::share('elements', $elements);
 }
 }
```

Or Create blade file(elements.blade.php for your case), and put your variables

```
  <? $elements = \App\Http\Controllers\ElementController::getElements(); ?>
```

and include this file in whereever you want.

```
 @include('chat')

 {{use_it}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @djoo Welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

#### For JSON

If you are using json to render the view. Add it in your base controller:

```php
public function response($data)
{
    $elements = ...;
    return response(array_merge($data, ['elements' => $elements]));
}
```

And then whenever you need to return the data, all you have to do is pass the data array to the `$this->response($your_datas)` method and the response with the elements would be returned.

#### For Views:

If you are using render view. just use

```php
View::share('key', 'value');
```

check this [reference](https://laravel.com/docs/master/views#sharing-data-with-all-views)

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

You are right, Using service provider is the best way!
They are called view composers in Laravel, you can find it in the docs

Here is a sample

Register a new service provider and do this

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ViewServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        // Star means all views, but i would recommend you pass it to the General layout instead
        View::composer('*', function ($view) {
           $data = \App\Http\Controllers\ElementController::getElements();
           $view->with('collectionName',$data);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Just a note! don't call a controller like that! make a separate class! write the logic in it then inject it in Controller and in service provider (It's really bad practice), Good luck